# Why is <$> left associative?

Tags: haskell, apply, associativity

`fmap` is also `<$>` because it is function application (`$`) in the functor category.

```
(+5)  $  (*10)  $  10      -- 105
(+5) <$> (*10) <$> [1,2,3] -- [15,25,35]
```

Then I thought, well in that case `<*>` is function application in the applicative functor category, and this should work:

```
[(+5), (+10)] <*>  [(*10), (*100)] <*> [1,2,3]  -- ERROR
-- however:
[(+5), (+10)] <*> ([(*10), (*100)] <*> [1,2,3]) -- [15,25,35,...]
```

So, `<$>` only works out because `fmap` for functions happens to be postcomposition, so `(+5) <$> (*10)` becomes `(+5) . (*10)` which is then applied to `[1,2,3]`.

However left associativity for all the application operators (`<<=` included) seems to me like a poor design choice, especially after they recognized the similarity to `$` which is already right-associative. Is there another reason for this?

Comment: Function application is inherently left-associative; a better question would be why is `$` right-associative?

Comment: Also, `fmap` is better thought of as function *lifting* rather than function application. Once `fmap` returns the lifted function, it is applied the same as any other function; no special application required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really, the reason is probably just that it allows `<$>` and `<*>` to share one precedence level. We definitely want `<*>` to be left-associative so stuff like

```
Prelude> foldr <$> [(+),(*)] <*> [0,1] <*> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
[6,15,7,16,0,0,6,120]
```

works, and this also makes `<$>` behave the correct way even though it doesn't have higher precedence. Actually chaining multiple `<$>` operators is indeed not very useful with left-associativity.

*However, it would also not be very useful with right-associativity*. As chepner commented, it's actually a bit funny that `$` is right-associative. Sure, that allows writing compositions like

```
Prelude> sum $ map (+3) $ take 19 $ cycle [4..7]
160
```

but then, this could just as well be written as the arguably more elegant

```
Prelude> sum . map (+3) . take 19 . cycle $ [4..7]
160
```

(more elegant I say, because here the computation-chain is parsed as a single functional pipeline, rather than imperative-style “do this, then that, then...”). Thanks to the functor laws, this can be done just the same way with `<$>` and `.` as with `$` and `.`.

The only reason why you might prefer the multiple-`$` style is that it allows infix expressions in the pipeline, perhaps the most common example being lens updates (which are typically written with the flipped `&`, but the principle is the same):

```
Prelude Control.Lens> [4..7] & ix 1+~9 & ix 2*~8
[4,14,48,7]
```

This works because `$` and `&` have very low precedence, pretty much lower than any infix operator. That's not the case for `<$>` so you can't do

```
Prelude Control.Lens> ix 1+~9 <$> [[4..8], [5..9]]

<interactive>:23:1: error:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix ‘+~’ [infixr 4] and ‘<$>’ [infixl 4] in the same infix expression
```

In such a case, you *need* to use some parentheses anyway, and then you might as well do it with the also low-precedence composition operators from `Control.Category`:

```
Prelude Control.Lens Control.Category> (ix 1+~9 >>> ix 2*~8) <$> [[4..8], [5..9]]
[[4,14,48,7,8],[5,15,56,8,9]]
```

or with parens around each updater:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (ix 1+~9) . (ix 2*~8) <$> [[4..8], [5..9]]
[[4,14,48,7,8],[5,15,56,8,9]]
```